# Verificar quais números são primos dentro de um vetor

Tags: python, array

Estou com dificuldade nessa atividade:

> b) Módulo que recebe como parâmetro um vetor de números inteiros e retorna a quantidade de números primos no vetor. Este módulo deve chamar a função `IsPrime` da próxima pergunta.
>
> c) Um módulo que recebe um número inteiro positivo como parâmetro e retorna verdadeiro se o número for primo ou falso se o número não for primo. O método `NumberOfPrimes` deve chamar o método `IsPrime`.

Eu estou lendo o vetor assim:

```
vetor = []
valor = int(input('Digite o tamanho do vetor: '))

while len(vetor) < valor:
    vetor.append(int(input('Digite um numero: ')))

print('=' * 50)
print("Seu vetor é: {0}".format(vetor))
print('=' * 50)
```

Mas quando preciso passar por cada elemento do vetor, e fazer uma verificação e contar se é primo, sai errado.

```
c = 0
qntPrimo = 0

for elemento in vetor:
    for divisor in range(1, elemento +1):
        if elemento % divisor == 0:
            c = c + 1
    if c == 2:
        qntPrimo += 1
        print(qntPrimo)
```

Comment: "*sai errado*", o que "sai"? E o que deveria sair?

Comment: no caso do item b, deveria mostrar a só a quantidade de num primos dentro do vetor. se eu mandar rodar do jeito q coloquei aqui, ele executa só a parte da leitura do vetor e o print dele inteiro.

Comment: Na parte de calcular o primo ele não mostra nada no console.

Comment: Só mostrará se houver algum valor primo. No vetor que testou havia pelo menos um número primo?

Comment: sim, eu to sempre colocando os valores [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] pra testar

Comment: O valor de `c` não deveria reiniciar a cada elemento?

Comment: Como assim? Eu uso o c como um contador de qnts vezes aquele elemento é dividido.

Comment: Não só aquele... mas todos eles, na mesma variável.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, ou como fazer.

Answer (score -2):

Ola, espero que compreenda a minha explicação caso não vamos dialogando :p

explicação do loop:
Após informar os valores (tamanho do vetor), terá que expandir o numero  , a função range vai gera números de um intervalo até o limite especificado.
digitado um vetor de 1 posição e depois digitado numero 5...range retornara  o numero de  2,3,4,5.
primeiro loop é do tamanho do vetor e o segundo gera o tamanho informado pelo
valor do vetor.

Abaixo do segundo for, a verificação o if  testa se o resto da divisão de um numero por  outro vai ser 0(zero) sendo assim é múltiplo do antecessor e não é primo enquanto foi acrescentando na variável chamada de  "primo" o resultado  sera de múltiplos e não primo contra partida se na interação dos loops não houver acréscimos na variável "primo" indicara que o numero é primo devido o resto da divisão não é 0

```
vetor = []
primo=0
valor = int(input('Digite o tamanho do vetor: '))

while len(vetor) < valor:
    vetor.append(int(input('Digite um numero: ')))

#Os números primos são os números naturais que podem ser divididos por apenas dois fatores: o número um e ele mesmo.
for indice in range(len(vetor)):
   for percorrer in range(2,vetor[indice]):
     if vetor[indice] %  percorrer == 0:
        print("Numeros multiplos", vetor[indice])
        primo+=1
   if primo ==0:
     print("Numero primo",vetor[indice])





print('=' * 50)
print("Seu vetor é: {0}".format(vetor))
print('=' * 50)
```

Comment: Oi, boa noite, eu acho que entendi seu código, só não tenho certeza o que significa vetor[indice], acho que nunca vi essa sintaxe antes.

Comment: Achei legal tbm como vc usou o proprio vetor para percorrer a lista, eu não consegui formatar de um jeito que fosse. Acho q era a propria sintaxe q eu não tava entendendo. tipo : for x in range(1, vetor). assim dava erro, mas com esse len faz todo sentido.

Comment: len() retorno o tamanho do verto. entao "for i in range(len(vetor)): quando dar um print em "i" retornava as posições

Comment: esse vetor[indice]... manualmente seria algo como vertor[0].. ou vetor[1]... q retorna o conteudo no vertor na posição 0 ou 1... o  "[indice]" é a posição do vetor.

Comment: Toppp entendii agora. Obrigada demais!